# Why does read() read one byte at a time if char is 2 bytes?

Tags: java, io

If we have a character in our text file which is in unicode, mustn't it be 2 bytes of data?
But the `read()` method reads one byte at a time as an `int`. So if we have a `FileInputStream` object `fin` and we invoke `int x = fin.read()` once, how do we get the full character back upon `System.out.println(x)` if only one byte has been read? (the `fin.read()` is not in a `while` loop or anything, it is just called once)

Comment: It reads one byte at a time, because it is specified to read one byte at a time. If you need to deal with Strings nicely, you will have to use a decorator.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but the linked question's accepted answer explains the difference between reading bytes and characters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good question! You're right that *in Java* characters are always two bytes, but that isn't true elsewhere (e.g. in the contents of a file).

A file is not encoded "in "Unicode" because [Unicode](http://unicode.org/standard/WhatIsUnicode.html) is a specification, not an encoding. Encodings map the Unicode specification to certain byte sequences, and not all such encodings use two-byte characters. Java `char`s are [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) which is always two bytes wide, but many files are stored as [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) which is variable-width; ASCII chars are one byte, others are two or more.

More to the point however, [`InputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) is designed to read binary data, *not* characters, and binary data is (essentially) always read one byte at a time. If you want to read text you wrap your stream in a [`Reader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html) (preferably explicitly specifying the encoding to be used) to convert the binary data into text. Internally it will call `read()` one or more times in order to properly construct a character from the sequence of bytes based on the encoding.

Answer (score 4):

Streams are for reading bytes, not characters. If you want to read characters, use a `Reader`. The Reader will read characters one at a time, and will deal with characters decoding from bytes: depending on the character encoding (and the character itself), a character can be encoded in a single byte, two or even more.